# Why does AWS API Gateway Cognito Authroizer change the JWT payload in extracted claims?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

As I understand it, AWS Cognito Authorizer for AWS API Gateway automatically validates the JWT and parses the payload and includes some of the claims in the `event.requestContext.authorizer.claims` part of `event` parameter passed to lambda integration.

This is convenient because it means I don't have to manually extract data from the JWT, but the format for some of the claims (especially `cognito:groups`) gets changed during this process.

For example, the following JWT payload:

```json
{
  "sub": "xxx",
  "cognito:groups": [
    "group-a",
    "group-b"
  ],
  "email_verified": true,
  "iss": "https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxx",
  "cognito:username": "xxx",
  "given_name": "xxx",
  "origin_jti": "xxx",
  "aud": "xxx",
  "event_id": "xxx",
  "token_use": "id",
  "auth_time": 1666606318,
  "exp": 1666692718,
  "iat": 1666606318,
  "family_name": "xxx",
  "jti": "xxx",
  "email": "xxx"
}
```

results in the following parameters being passed to the lambda `event.requestContext.authorizer.claims`:

```json
{
  "sub": "xxx",
  "cognito:groups": "group-a,group-b",
  "email_verified": "true",
  "iss": "https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxx",
  "cognito:username": "xxx",
  "given_name": "xxx",
  "origin_jti": "xxx",
  "aud": "xxx",
  "event_id": "xxx",
  "token_use": "id",
  "auth_time": "1666606318",
  "exp": "Tue Oct 25 10:11:58 UTC 2022",
  "iat": "Mon Oct 24 10:11:58 UTC 2022",
  "family_name": "xxx",
  "jti": "xxx",
  "email": "xxx"
}
```

Notably, the `cognito:groups` parameter changes from an array of strings to a string concatenating elements of that list with a comma delimiter, the `email_verified` also changes from a boolean to a string, the `exp` and `iat` dates are now parsed, `auth_time` becomes a string etc.

This is particularly annyoing because running the code that relies on the extraction of these parameters, such as local environments which bypass the authorizer or tests comparing values in provided jwt need to account for this undocumented behaviour.

Is there a respository containing code for the authorizer where I could submit a PR, or perhaps a way of altering this behaviour?

---

**UPDATE (24/10/2022):**

The only relevant documentation entry I have found for this is the following excerpt from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html):

> In the input to the backend Lambda function, the requestContext object is a map of key-value pairs. In each pair, the key is the name of a $context variable property, and the value is the value of that property. API Gateway may add new keys to the map.
>
> Depending on the features that are enabled, the requestContext map may vary from API to API. For example, in the preceding example, no authorization type is specified, so no $context.authorizer.* or $context.identity.* properties are present. When an authorization type is specified, this causes API Gateway to pass authorized user information to the integration endpoint in a requestContext.identity object as follows:
>
> When the authorization type is AWS_IAM, the authorized user information includes $context.identity.* properties.
>
> When the authorization type is COGNITO_USER_POOLS (Amazon Cognito authorizer), the authorized user information includes $context.identity.cognito* and $context.authorizer.claims.* properties.
>
> When the authorization type is CUSTOM (Lambda authorizer), the authorized user information includes $context.authorizer.principalId and other applicable $context.authorizer.* properties.

I supose this might suggest that the `event.contextRequest` is limited to only passing key-value pairs with string types?

Comment: Hi @Marceli, I also stumble upon this issue, it was annoying as hell. Any update on how you handle it?

Comment: @Toan, at present I just take into account this undocumented behaviour and work around it by parsing the data to the desired format. For cognito:groups variable this means splitting by `,` (comma), for booleans it's checking the string value etc.
I think it would be a better option to just bypass it altogether and parse the JWT token in middleware as suggested by @gary-archer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75989525/5683522).

Comment: I just stumbled upon this issue! In my case the stringified array has a different format: `'cognito:groups': '[f5569c3a-a62f-429b-b993-a57c79c6c96c]'`. Very annoying and I hope it won't chnage when I add a second group.

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd post some thoughts that are related, in terms of desired behaviour of how an API architecture should work. I am going beyond the scope of your question though.

**USEFUL QUALITIES**

- API calls work the same on a development computer as in the cloud
- APIs can forward JWT access tokens to each other to flow the user identity in a verifiable way
- You are in control of JWT error handling, logging and auditing

**AUTHORIZER BEHAVIOUR**

There is a convenience to configuring an authorizer, after which a JSON string is forwarded to lambdas in an HTTP header. This is not the most secure behaviour, and in some alternative setups could be abused by someone sending malicious headers.

**ZERO TRUST BEHAVIOUR**

An emerging trend - mostly in cloud native setups - is for every API to validate the JWT access token on every request, rather than the gateway. This protects against internal threats. It also enables lambdas to receive the JWT and forward it to each other in HTTP requests, so that the caller identity remains verifiable. Doing so also ensures identical behaviour in all environments.

**LAMBDA ZERO TRUST**

My [Serverless API](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.serverless) follows this approach, to authorize using AWS Cognito access tokens, doing so by avoiding use of an authorizer, and doing the work in the lambda itself. The API code therefore has full control over claims, error handling, logging etc.

**VALIDATING A JWT**

This code to perform this task is actually simple and only requires a [few lines of code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.serverless/blob/master/src/plumbing/oauth/oauthAuthenticator.ts#L41). Unfortunately, the fact that token signing public keys cannot be stored in memory between requests, is the downside to my API. It adds complexity and a performance cost, though I mitigate it as best I can.

**SUMMARY**

If lambdas provided a simpler cross request storage option I would recommend avoiding use of the authorizer for JWT validation, and doing the JWT work in the lambda itself.

In your current setup, perhaps a [lambda middleware class](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.serverless/blob/master/src/plumbing/oauth/oauthAuthorizer.ts) is the simplest option to solve your problems. In AWS this could translate claims back to the JWT format before thd lambda's main code executes, and be a do no-op in local test setups.